# Configuring babel & webpack for an IE11-compatible web library: spread operator in dependecy function argument

Tags: internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, browserify, babel-loader

I've been building out a web library for a while now, but hadn't been testing on IE11 much. I recently noticed that the output code included a spread operator in the arguments of a function, which threw an error in Internet Explorer.

At first, I thought this would be a simple fix with [a babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-parameters), until I noticed the source code that was being transformed. It was part of a dependency, `debug`.

[Source code in dependency](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/backport/4.1.1/src/browser.js) (`/src/browser.js:172`):

```
/**
 * Invokes `console.log()` when available.
 * No-op when `console.log` is not a "function".
 *
 * @api public
 */
function log(...args) {
    // This hackery is required for IE8/9, where
    // the `console.log` function doesn't have 'apply'
    return typeof console === 'object' &&
        console.log &&
        console.log(...args);
}
```

Browserified version on npm (`/dist/debug.js:813`):

```
        /**
         * Invokes `console.log()` when available.
         * No-op when `console.log` is not a "function".
         *
         * @api public
         */


        function log() {
          var _console;

          // This hackery is required for IE8/9, where
          // the `console.log` function doesn't have 'apply'
          return (typeof console === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _typeof(console)) === 'object' && console.log && (_console = console).log.apply(_console, arguments);
        }
```

Webpacked version within my library:

```
/**
 * Invokes `console.log()` when available.
 * No-op when `console.log` is not a "function".
 *
 * @api public
 */


function log(...args) {
  // This hackery is required for IE8/9, where
  // the `console.log` function doesn't have 'apply'
  return typeof console === 'object' && console.log && console.log(...args);
}
```

So, it looks like babel & webpack are breaking code that was already IE-compatible. **Why would that happen?** Is it an issue of webpack and broserify not working together? Maybe I need to switch from UMD to CommonJS or something?

Here's my configuration files (though I've tried a lot of variations):

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": "58",
          "firefox": "54",
          "ie": "11",
          "safari": "10",
          "opera": "44",
          "edge": "16"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const env = require('yargs').argv.env; // use --env with webpack 2
const pkg = require('./package.json');

let libraryName = pkg.name;

let outputFile, mode;

if (env === 'build') {
  mode = 'production';
  outputFile = libraryName + '.min.js';
} else {
  mode = 'development';
  outputFile = libraryName + '.js';
}

const config = {
  mode: mode,
  entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/lib',
    filename: outputFile,
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve('./node_modules'), path.resolve('./src')],
    extensions: ['.json', '.js'],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Can you post the detailed error message? Besides, please check your code to make sure you have installed and import the Polyfills. And, here is an article about [Working with Babel 7 and Webpack](https://www.thebasement.be/working-with-babel-7-and-webpack/), you could check it.

Comment: The only error message is from Internet Explorer, when the webpack output is loaded: `SCRIPT1010: Unexpected Identifier`. It points to the line and column in the webpack output of the first spread operator: `function log(...args)`. I'll take a read through that link, though. Thanks.

Comment: I've read through the intro article and even tried updating to babel 7.5, but stil no luck. So, I've created a simplified project here, that highlights the error. Does that help? https://github.com/carpiediem/webpacked-debug

Comment: Hmm, just stumbled on this issue. That might be the ticket...
https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/689#issuecomment-487919519

Comment: It suggests two options: modifying the exclude configuration and downgrading to debug@3.2.6. The config tweak didn't fix my problem, but downgrading did. Maybe that's my best option.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to downgrade the dependency to debug@3.2.6, since the bug [seems to have appeared in the later versions](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/689).